# Can server-side generated javascript be optimized in require.js?

Tags: php, requirejs

I'm very new to require.js, and I've been beginning to think about how I'll go about optimization.  My understanding is that you basically point `r.js` at your `main.js` or whatever other top-level javascript entrypoints you have setup, and it does it's magic.

What I'm wondering, is whether it would work if `main.js` were generated on the server side, let's say by PHP.  I could go into details on the reason for this, but it basically has to do with the way in which modules (3rd party included) will tap into the system in order to add different modules as dependencies.

So, I guess this boils down to whether `r.js` requests a URL over http (locally) or whether it loads up the file over the local file system.  I noticed the `baseUrl` configuration parameter in the build profile, which leads me to think that it can be a URL - but in all the examples it's just a local path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require.js loads JavaScript over HTTP.  The examples aren't local paths, they are simply relative paths.  Require.js does not know or care what happens server-side, so you could certainly dynamically generate JavaScript.

However, you might want to reconsider your architecture a bit since it sounds like you are going down the path of a system that is hard to maintain, and hard to set appropriate client-side caching.

Comment: Thanks Brad!  Fantastic.  Client-side caching shouldn't really be a problem - appropriate cache headers can be sent with the generated main.js.